# How can I only have a gh-pages branch?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm doing some basic demos with javascript pages - using github not only as source control but also as a hosting provider.

I'd like to work only on the gh-pages branch, or have it automatically reflect my changes on master, whatever is easier and cleaner.

I tried to delete the master branch but it won't let me:

```
$ git push origin --delete master
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To git@github.com:opensas/geo-demo.git
! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

I just want to have a single branch (master or gh-pages) and whatever I commit and push to it to appear in the github pages.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to remove master from GitHub you have to go to GitHub and set gh-pages as your default branch. Only then can you delete master.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set the "Default Branch" to "gh-pages" in your repo's settings page, then delete the `master` branch:

```
$ git push origin :master
```

It should works.

Comment: Be careful about deleting the master branch. Make sure everyone that uses the repo knows what's happening, make sure there are no unmerged PRs on the master branch, and that all commits to master have been merged to gh-pages. On balance, I think it's probably best to leave the master branch intact for a week or two after changing the default. I speak from experience ;).

Comment: @SamDutton yeah, good suggestion, totally make sense. but this is what op wants to do in this case. ;)

Comment: @kJuy yep — I'm only warning because I got burned :).

Comment: @SamDutton hahahaha lol b.t.w., GitHub/BitBucket both offer Branch Protection feature, a good way to avoid removing important branches. It's worth using ;)